# Rich:DataTable sorting breaks when row contains h:commandLink

Tags: jsf, webkit, richfaces

I have a [rich:dataTable](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/rich_column.html#sort) with sorting. Each row in the table has a h:commandlink through to another page. This works fine in all non webkit browsers.

When sorting by clicking the header the contents of the table is cleared and the following error is displayed in the Chrome JavaScript console:

```
Uncaught Error: NOT_SUPPORTED_ERR: DOM Exception 9
```

This appears to be a known issue (https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RF-6096) but without any solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that using:

```
<a4j:commandLink ... />
```

instead of

```
<h:commandlink .../>
```

Resolves all issues with the table sorting.

(I could not log in to the JBoss issue tracker to add this comment, so if you have access and this works for you please add a comment.)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a problem with webkit implementation of document.importNode. To circumvent this problem you can use this little piece of javascript code on your template file:

```
if( /webkit/.test( navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase() ) ){
    var _importNode = window.document.importNode;
    window.document.importNode = function(node, deep){
        try{
            return _importNode.apply(this, arguments);
        } catch(e) {
            if( e.code == DOMException.NOT_SUPPORTED_ERR ){
                // clone and adopt
                return document.adoptNode(node.cloneNode(deep));
            }
            throw e;
        }
    };
}
```